# How to return the right positive number in python whithou changing the initial variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have create functions to simulate ATM system, when asking the user to make deposit everything goes well but the problem is when the user make a withdraw. If the amount is greater than the balance I have the new balance in negative value. And need some help to correct this behavior.

**My functions:**

```
def show_balance(balance):
    print(f"Current Balance: ${balance}")

def deposit(balance):
    amount = input("Enter amount to deposit: ")
    amount = float(amount)
    result = balance + amount
    return result

def withdraw(balance):
    withdraw = input("Enter amount to withdraw: ")
    withdraw = float(withdraw)
    result = balance - withdraw    
    return result
```

**Here is when using the functions:**

```
# Display ATM menu to user
while True:
    option = input("Choose an option: ")
    if option == "1":
        account.show_balance(balance)
    elif option == "2":
        balance = account.deposit(balance)
        account.show_balance(balance)
    elif option == "3":        
        balance = account.withdraw(balance)
        account.show_balance(balance)
        while True:
            if balance < 0:
                print("You do not have this money?")
                break
    else:
        print("Please, provide a valid option")
```

Now when adding 50 using option "2" everithing works well. When the withdraw is < the balance (55) it just return a nagative value (-5). I want to print the massage: "You do not have this money?", but also keep the balance to the right amount (50 -55) => balance remain 50 and ask the user to try again.

Comment: Well, your `withdraw` function should probably check for the condition before returning a new `result`?

Comment: You are right, thank you @AKX just imagine the way to do it, and fix it. Everything is done within the withdraw function. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

@AKX -> Based on your precious advice, I have fixed the function doing the following:

```
def withdraw(balance):
    withdraw = input("Enter amount to withdraw: ")
    withdraw = float(withdraw)
    if withdraw <= balance:
        result = balance - withdraw    
        return result
    elif withdraw > balance:
        print("You do not have this money?")
        return balance
```